# Download images (.png and .eps formats) using php

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

I am trying to *download* the icons/logos of the formats *.png and .eps* using php form submit action. I am able to download the .png format images, but unable to download .eps format images.

I use `header('Content-Type: image/png');` for `.png` files.

Is there any way to achieve this for `.eps` files?

Also, is there any possibility to achieve image file download through ajax without reloading or submitting form ?

Any help/suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `image/x-eps`...

Comment: @I'L'I. thank you for the help on image content-type